# ServiceStack "Declaration referenced in a method implementation cannot be a final method"

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Trying to set up `ServiceStack` with `OrmLite` to connect to my local `SQL` instance. Getting error

> "Declaration referenced in a method implementation cannot be a final
>   method"

and it's driving me nuts. Here are my steps so far:

1. New "ServiceStack ASP.NET Empty" project
2. In the "Service" project, installed ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer
   NuGet package
3. Added the following code to the AppHost "Configure" section:

`public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
     {
          var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApiDbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
          container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
                    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));
          OrmLiteConnectionFactory dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider);`
      }

Here are my using statements:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Data;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer;
using LRIService.ServiceInterface;
```

I would like to use this database connection throughout the app for caching, data access, and eventually user authentication.

Lastly, are there any good examples of `ServiceStack` running as a standalone service (not as part of an `ASP.NET MVC` app)? I am going to be accessing this via a stand-alone AngularJS app that may or may not be hosted on the same domain (I've worked with the `CORS` feature before). I'm just having trouble separating the `ASP.NET MVC` stuff from the `ServiceStack` stuff in many of the examples on the web.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message sounds like you're mixing different versions of ServiceStack together. Try clearing your [NuGet packages Cache](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet#redownloading-myget-packages). Alternatively you can try the most recent [v4.0.34 packages on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

As for non ASP.NET MVC Examples, most of the [ServiceStack Live Demos](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/LiveDemos) are **Single Page Apps** that don't use ASP.NET MVC at all:

- [Chat](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat) (jQuery + ss-utils.js)

  - [Entire App ILMerged into a single cross-platform Chat.exe](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Gap/tree/master/src/Chat) (Self Host)
  - [React Chat](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat-React) (port to React.js)
- [Http Benchmarks](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HttpBenchmarks) (jQuery + ss-utils.js)
- [Email Contacts](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/EmailContacts) (jQuery + ss-utils.js)
- [Stack API's](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/StackApis) (Angular JS)
- [Imgur](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Imgur) (jQuery)
- [Todos](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Todos) (Backbone.js)
- [Razor Rockstars](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/RazorRockstars)

  - [ASP.NET host](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/RazorRockstars/tree/master/src/RazorRockstars.WebHost)
  - [A Stand-alone, self-hosted HttpListener](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/RazorRockstars/tree/master/src/RazorRockstars.SelfHost) (Self Host)
  - [A Stand-alone Windows Service](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/RazorRockstars/tree/master/src/RazorRockstars.WinService) (Self Host)
- **Self-hosted HttpListener** with

  - [Entire App ILMerged into a single cross-platform App.exe](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Gap#self-hosting-console-app)
  - [Hosted inside WinForms with Chromium Embedded Framework](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Gap#winforms-with-chromium-embedded-framework)
  - [Hosted inside Mac OSX Cocoa App with Xmarain.Mac](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Gap#mac-osx-cocoa-app-with-xmarainmac)
- [REST Files](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/RestFiles) (jQuery)
- [Redis StackOverflow](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/RedisStackOverflow) (jQuery)

Comment: You da man. I uninstalled all v4.0.33 ServiceStack packages, cleared the cache, and reinstalled v4.0.34 from MyGet. Runs great! And thanks for the links. Lots of research to do now!